# High/low order of the 4 select inputs of a 16-to-1 SN74150 MUX

Tags: texas-instruments, binary, multiplexer

I'm looking at a Texas Instrument Data sheet for an SN74150 16-to-1 MUX but I can't find which of the select inputs (A, B, C, D) is the higher order and which is the lower order. Does anyone know which is which?

Comment: Did you miss the function table on page 2?

Comment: @brhans oh goodness, I completely ignored that. Thank you!!